# Does anyone know the following AWS Cloud Formation error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

When deploying my Cloud Formation templates, which includes an Elastic Beanstalk Stack, i get the following error:

> Access Denied: S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-platform-assets-eu-central-1, S3Key=stalks/eb_corretto11_amazon_linux_2_1.0.2777.0_20211016030628/packs/Corretto11Template.pack (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InsufficientPrivilegesException; Request ID: 5a2d57e4-cd43-443b-9407-b0fc0234ea40; Proxy: null)

Since its an S3 Error (InsufficientPrivilegesException) i seem to be missing a permission. The problem is that the S3 Bucket it cant access isnt in my Accounts S3 Bucket List and seems to be kind of a regional bucket, so i cant add policies... Has anyone ever encountered this error?
For background info: Im working in an account inside an root account which uses AWS Organisations...

Heres my iam role template including the managed policy arn:

```
BackendServiceRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  RoleName:  !Sub '${GroupName}BackendServiceRole'
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
  ManagedPolicyArns: [arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy]
```

In my Backend Template in the Enviroment, ive added the following OptionSetting:

```
MyEnvironment:
Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
Properties:
  ApplicationName: !Ref MyBackendApplication
  CNAMEPrefix: !Sub '${ApplicationName}'
  EnvironmentName: !Sub '${ApplicationName}-Environment'
  SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.7 running Corretto 11
  Tier:
    Name: WebServer
    Type: Standard
  OptionSettings:
    - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
      OptionName: ServiceRole
      Value: !GetAtt BackendServiceRole.Arn
    # bunch of other options here
```

Thanks already!

Comment: Are you sure that you can even use S3 bucket from different account?

Comment: @Marcin what do you mean by that? I never intentionally mention this bucket, if that answers your question. But thats the bucket that is in the Exception and its not in my S3 Bucket list

Comment: Have you checked if [this AWS forum entry](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151395) helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy AWS Managed policy to your service role. You can read details in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/security-iam-awsmanpol.html).

This policy will grant you access to the required bucket:

[image]

The full policy document is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-servicerole.html#iam-servicerole-policy).

Make sure that you properly assign the role to your configuration template:

```
  EBSApplicationConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref EBSApplication
      Description: ElasticBeanstalk Configuration Template
      SolutionStackName: !Ref SolutionStackName
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: EnvironmentType
          Value: LoadBalanced
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: ServiceRole
          Value: !GetAtt BackendServiceRole.Arn
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! Although your answer actually makes sense and in my opinion should work, it sadly doesnt.... I added my updated iam role template to the question

Comment: thank you again! Now, to my confusion, a Validation Error is thrown... the following: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource BackendServiceRole. The error wasnt thrown when i used !Ref BackendServiceRole before...

Comment: Also, the difference is that im doing this in my Environment, and not in the Configuration Template, which i dont have... i set the settings directly when creating the enviroment. Isnt this possible overall? or did i just probably mess up the syntax? i double checked and the syntax should be alright, but i might miss something

Comment: It would be better to post your full template. It should be the same, defining the options in the environment. You can follow the example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html

Comment: Also the error you get means that there isn't a resource named BackendServiceRole. Perhaps you are naming your role differently or there is a typo

Comment: the thing is that there is, its a parameter in this template file

Comment: i added the rest of the enviroment resource template

Comment: in this case, im also confused, why !Ref BackendServiceRole isnt enough, want to set the Role and not the Policy right? Cause in my head, !GetAtt BackendServiceRole.Arn should reference to the managed policy shouldnt it? But what i want and need here is a role, isnt it?

Comment: !Ref returns the name of the role and !GetAtt Arn returns the arn. You need to provide the role Arn and the role name in the settings. Check your template for typos and spacing errors. I also recommend https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint

Comment: okay, then the Problem is that i only pass the BackendServiceRole as a string and not a resource into the stack. I tried passing the arn directly as a string and referencing it, but also doesnt work. Am i able to pass whole resources through stacks?

Comment: You can't pass resources through stacks. You should be able to pass ARNs as string though. Define an Output with !GetAtt BackendServiceRole.Arn in one stack and pass it ti the next one as a parameter.

Comment: that is exactly what ive done and it doesnt work.... !GetAtt BackendServiceRole.Arn in the Outputs and then Value: !Ref BackendServiceRole in the Setting... Do you see a mistake there? It somehow still doesnt work, although this would make sense to work... i double checked and the value gets passed correct.

Comment: Better to post a new question with the needed details...

Comment: i could, but isnt it still the same question?

Comment: You could ask why you can't pass Arn as string from one stack to another. Alternatively post your templates in this question.

Comment: the thing is that i cann pass the arn. If i look into the Cloudformation "Logs" Parameters, the backend stack gets the correct arn, but somehow it either doesnt set it right or it just doesnt work. But i will worry about this on monday at earliest. Thanks for your help this far!